# Can MS bot service message end point detect user's edit behavior?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

**Context**

Currently we are using Azure Bot Service. The Bot Service is setting up an **message endpoint** which is directed to our on-pre server

We can successful detect an request coming in when user send something through bot.
But when user edit the previous messages, not request comes in

Message endpoint on Azure
[image]

**User send a new message on bot**
[image]

**User edit a message on bot**
[image]

**Question**

Does there exists a way to receive the update request when users edit their previous messages on bot?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to get update request over the endpoint when user edits the message

Comment: Hi, Do you have any other idea on how to get update?

Comment: You can subscribe to messages to get change notifications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link mentioned below to verify "**`Update Activity`**" section which is nearer to the current requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#update-activity

Comment: hello, This is a way to update sent message, what i want to know is to detect update when user edit their message